# How to remove the unwanted data from parsing result

Tags: iphone, ios

iam developing one application.In that iam using  the xml parsing.That xml file contain the 4 category tags and other tags.From the xml file i want to get the data of category tag.At the time of getting the category data,every time i print the array of category values.That show correctly.But after completion of parsing, another tag data will be append to last category name.My parsing code is like below.

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
if(self.presentvalue)
{
    [presentvalue appendString:string];
}
}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{

if(![elementName compare:@"category"])
{
    [categories addObject:presentvalue];
    NSLog(@"%@",presentvalue);
    NSLog(@"Number of elements %@",categories);
}

}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
if([elementName isEqualToString:@"category"])
{
    presentvalue=[NSMutableString string];  
}
}
```

And my xml file content is like

```
    <lesson>
   <categories>
   <category id="1">1</category>
   <category id="2">2</category>
   <category id="3">3</category>
   </categories>
   <references>
    <reference id="1" type="youtube" categoryid="2" name="Boyles law">
    <url><![CDATA[http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J_I8Y-i4Axc]]>
     </url>
    </reference>
    </references>
    </lesson>
```

From this xml i got the array values like 1,2,3http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J_I8Y-i4Axc.Like this i got the result.So please tell me how to get the category values without that extra data.

Comment: Can you include the output from those NSLog statements. Are you looking to just get 1,2 and 3 in your array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"category"]) {
    NSLog(@"Node is found correctly");
    if(presentvalue == nil)
        presentvalue = [NSMutableString string];
    else 
        [presentvalue setString:@""];
}
else {
    presentvalue = nil;
}

}


- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{

[presentvalue appendString:string];
if (presentvalue) 
{
   [self.tempArray addObject:presentvalue]; // add this line. create a tempArray containing all the strings.
    presentvalue = nil;
}
}
```

this should help u in your parsing. hope it helps. happy coding :)

Comment: No use.Same output will be coming.

Comment: [self.tempArray addObject:presentvalue]; // add this line above presentvalue = nil  and remove the NSLog in that method. create a tempArray which will contain all the strings. print the tempArray to check the results.

Answer (score 0):

place check in your xml parsing code. that if the starting/ending element name is category. add objects to array else do nothing. just passout

Comment: 1st thing post your code of found charectr and found cdata too

Comment: 2nd is you are not assinging atributes to the array that are in category. are u familiar with attributes?

Comment: 1st thing i already posted my found character code.And i dont need that address so i didn't write cdata code.And 2nd i dont want  that category attribute values i need only category tag value.

Answer (score 0):

I think this line look strange

```
if(![elementName compare:@"category"])
```

Shouldn't it be like this? (without !)

```
if([elementName compare:@"category"])
```

edited

Try replacing this to the didEndElement

```
if([elementName isEqualToString:@"category"])
{
    [categories addObject:presentvalue];
    presentValue = [NSMutableString string];
    NSLog(@"%@",presentvalue);
    NSLog(@"Number of elements %@",categories);
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"category"])` it doesn't make sense to use compare:, and certainly not to use !compare. What is the statement supposed to be doing?

Comment: Exactly. Anyway, this is not the case with this problem.

Comment: I think your presentValue is still pointed after didEndElement and the foundCharacters will get called even if it's not the category tag. After you allocated the presentValue for the last category, you didn't release or do anything with it so it still points to the latest one. Try allocating new presentValue in the didEndElement function.
You have to remove the ! from the "if" like I stated before though.